# FATAL_ERROR|System.TypeException: That operation is only allowed from within an active site. Class.System.Site.createPortalUser

Tags: api, force.com-sites, rest

This is my code.But am getting an error i.e

> FATAL_ERROR|System.TypeException: That operation is only allowed from
>   within an active site.  Class.System.Site.createPortalUser.

Please correct my error

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/insertP/*')
global with sharing class portalcreatenew
{
@HttpPost
global static string newportalcreation()
{
    RestRequest req=RestContext.request;
   // req.addParameter('userId',userId);
    RestResponse res=RestContext.response;
   // req.addParameter('userId',userId);

    Blob Body = req.requestBody;
    Wrapperclss reg = portalcreatenew.parse(Body.tostring());
    //system.debug('InputParsed::'+reg.Wrapper2);
   // system.debug('InputRequest::'+Body.tostring());
    Wrapperclss container = (Wrapperclss)System.JSON.deserialize(RestContext.request.requestBody.tostring(),Wrapperclss.class);
    User thisUser = [select Id from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
    ID ProfileId = [Select id from Profile where name = 'Customer Portal Manager Custom'].id;
    Account A1 = new Account(Name = 'Test Acct', OwnerId=thisUser.Id );
    insert A1;
    Contact C1 = new Contact( AccountID = A1.id, firstName = 'TestTest', lastName = 'UserUser',email = 'harish.cherry484@gmail.com');
    insert C1; 
    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.Username = reg.Username;
   // newUser.LastName = C1.lastname;
    newUser.LastName = reg.Lastname;
    newUser.Email = reg.Email;
    //newUser.password = reg.password;
    newUser.Alias = reg.Alias;
    newUser.CommunityNickName = reg.CommunityNickName;
    newUser.TimeZoneSidKey = reg.TimeZoneSidKey;
    newUser.LocaleSidKey = reg.LocaleSidKey;
    newUser.EmailEncodingKey = reg.EmailEncodingKey;
    newUser.ProfileId = ProfileId;
    newUser.LanguageLocaleKey = reg.LanguageLocaleKey;
    newUser.ContactId = C1.id;
    string userId = Site.createPortalUser(newUser, A1.id, 'harish.8392', true);
    insert newUser;
    return 'User Created! Id Is: ' + newUser.Id;
    }
    public static Wrapperclss parse(string reg)
    {
        return(Wrapperclss)System.json.deserialize(reg,Wrapperclss.class);
    }
    global class Wrapperclss
    {
            public String Username{get;set;}
            public String LastName{get;set;}
            public String Email{get;set;} 
            public String password{get; set {password = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
            public String confirmPassword {get; set { confirmPassword = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
            public String Alias{get;set;}
            public String CommunityNickName{get;set;}
            public String TimeZoneSidKey{get;set;}
            public String LocaleSidKey{get;set;}
            public String EmailEncodingKey{get;set;}
            public String ProfileId{get;set;}
            public String LanguageLocaleKey{get;set;}
            public String ContactId{get;set;}
        }  
  }
```

Comment: Make the community active . Open active community URL in browser and test it from there, it will work.  `Createportaluser` will not work, when you directly open the VF page in your salesforce org session.

Answer (score 1):

When you tried to execute site methods as a Internal user then community will throw exception.

Make the community as active. open the community URL in browser and test it from community site page. It will not throw error.

`Site.createPortalUser()` is only work from community site pages.

Follow the Steps to Activate the Community:

Setup-->All Communities--> click on `Workspaces` for respective community --> Administraton --> Setting --> Click on `Active Community` button.

You can access it by hitting community URL and try registration functionality.

Comment: Am Creating Customer Portal .......,what is the need to activate communities

Comment: @Harish check my updated answer

Comment: HI Amol....,I activated communities but still am getting same error only. could u check this code in your DEV edition

Comment: @Harish make sure you are testing it from community link.  you need to pass existing account Id and portal create a contact for you, you don't need to create contact code. you can compare your code with https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm